# Why does my ApplicationContext fail to load when I enable web security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a Spring Boot application that I would like to add Spring Security too. So I've added the following configuration, which starts and runs just fine:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if(environment.acceptsProfiles("live")) {
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        }
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my functional tests fail to load the application context. All functional tests extend from the following configuration:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class, classes = MyConfiguration.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
class ContextInitializer extends GebReportingSpec {
}
```

When the tests attempts to load the application, it throws the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptSetupMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:471)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSetup(BaseSpecRunner.java:375)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSetup(BaseSpecRunner.java:370)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:323)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$6.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:309)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:471)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:288)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:278)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSimpleFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:269)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:263)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:246)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:480)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:463)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:238)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:188)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:98)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:480)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:463)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:67)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:105)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:360)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.<init>(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.defaultServletHandlerMapping(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bbac173.CGLIB$defaultServletHandlerMapping$25(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bbac173$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$59db630c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4bbac173.defaultServletHandlerMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 79 common frames omitted
```

Seems like I need to let the Integration test context loader know about the spring security somehow.

EDIT:

I've narrowed the problem down to a converter that pulls in a PasswordEncoder. Removing the converter and using the PasswordEncoder directly in the controller causes the problem to go away. Also, removing the Security Configuration will allow me to use the Converter just fine.

Here is a link to a repository I made that replicates the issue:
https://github.com/StephenTurley/SpringBootSecurityTest.git

The last commit causes the error. Not sure why I can't use spring converters and Spring security. Any ideas?

Comment: There have been problems with Spock's Spring support in the past. Have you tried it with plain JUnit? Also, what version of Spock are you using? A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be a big help here.

Comment: Haven't tried junit as all of our functional tests are written in Spock/Jeb and re-writing them is less than ideal. That being said, I'll throw together a small project today to reproduce the issue. and post it. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I should also add that our tests work fine when the security config is absent.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest that using JUnit was a solution, just that doing so could help to identify the cause of the problem

Comment: Remove `loader=` from the `@ContextConfiguration` or replace it with `AnnotationConfigWebContextLoader`.

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem and provided a repo the replicates it. See the edit above.

Comment: The [spring-boot-sample-web-method-security](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-method-security) archetype implements web security and functional testing. It might help to start with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is an initialization issue that is [fixed by adding DelegatingFilterProxy](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4165) support in Boot 1.3. I sent you a [pull request](https://github.com/StephenTurley/SpringBootSecurityTest/pull/1) that resolves the issue by updating to Spring Boot 1.3.2.RELEASE. It also resolves a few other dependency issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same problem sometime back and fixed it adding `javax.servlet-api` and `jsp-api` in **test scope**, can you try adding same dependencies, below for reference:

**For Maven:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**For Gradle:**

```
testCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1"
testCompile "javax.servlet:jsp-api:2.0"
```

Also make sure you have [spring-test](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test) dependency in **test scope** in your classpath.

Comment: No change after adding these dependencies.

Comment: @ZeroDivide: do you have spring-context(http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context) dependency in your `classpath`?

Comment: I assume that gets pulled in transitively from spring-boot. I'm writing a small example application to reproduce the issue now. Not sure if I'll get it finished by the end of my lunch break yet. I will share the repo when it is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I think in you application context shoul include the security context, so try to add that in you application context:

```
@Configuration
@Import({
    SecurityConfiguration.class
})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
   })
public class ApplicationContext {
}
```

Anothing, I think SecurityConfiguration should be called as SecurityContext.

Answer (score 0):

I may be lacking some context information here but have you tried:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Maybe one of your @Configuration classes is annotated with @EnableWebMvc??